# Laravel route get wrong param value

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have tried to inject local in route and it's working but when working on another route there is a issue appear to me first this is my `web.php` route contents

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{local}' ], function () {

    Route::get('/question/view/{question}/{slug?}', 'QuestionsController@show')->name('question_view');

});
```

then in inside show function

```
public function show($question, $slug)
{
    dd($question,$slug);
    //print en, 1
}
```

this is a url I have called

```
http://localhost:8000/en/question/view/1/hello
```

when I'm trying to read the value of `question` I got the `local` value `en` ! where is wrong ?

Comment: Add the url you are trying..

Comment: show url which you call

Comment: I have added the URL
http://localhost:8000/en/question/view/1/hello

Comment: Add a dummy variable in your show function to capture the 'en'. You're passing in 3 variables via the route, so it's passing in 3 variables to your function. Right now, you're only capturing the first two.

Comment: @aynber there is no way to escape the first variable the locale ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 params in route

```
public function show($prefix, $question, $slug)
{
    dd($prefix, $question,$slug);
    //print en, 1, hello
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your route have 3 param local , question and slug , your url will take that 3 param respectively , so try to take 3 param in function as well like

```
public function show($local, $question, $slug)
{

}
```